# Updating attributes, including PK and SK. Move up to 10 Billion records to new table, while still capturing live changes

Tags: migration, aws, dynamodb

Looking to shorten the attributes for some of our tables in DynamoDB, including the PK and SK and am currently brainstorming on what would be the best way to achieve this. The largest table has 10 billion records. Need to be able to keep system up and running (no downtime), so looking not only to move the data, but also continue to process data and ensure that the data is processed into new table as well.

One idea was to export tables to S3 and then use DMS to do a onetime dump and use lambda to process new changes at same time into table, but not sure how to handle if, say a new change comes in for an existing record before it's written in by DMS.

Could also try using AWS Glue and have also flirted with the idea of involving SQS/Kafka to store new changes and process after DMS dump is done.

Thoughts?